# Using Type to define new variable

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it is possible to use `Type` to convert an obect back to its original type.
I have my code like this now, but this does not work. I've looked on the internet but what i get are methods with generic types, like this.

```
public static T method<T>(string name)
{
    return (T)objects[name];
}
```

But i'm looking for something like this.

```
public static dynamic GetObject(string name)
{
   Type t = objects[name].GetType();
   t test = (t)objects[name]; <--- Is it possible to do something like this?
}
```

If this won't work, what would be an good way to get the same result?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: There is no way to get this result without reflection, which means you either a) are stuck in reflection-land forever more as far as using the return value is concerned or b) use `dynamic` and let the compiler do this behind the scenes. Even in the latter case, the taint of reflection (and runtime evaluation) will spread to anything that comes in contact with the return value, so IMHO "find another way to write your code" is a better rule of thumb than "use `dynamic`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to return the named object as `dynamic`, you don't need the type.  Just return it, and the runtime binding will handle this for you (or raise an exception at runtime).

```
public static dynamic GetObject(string name)
{
   return objects[name];
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. Many thanks. i have been struggling a couple of hours with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection to create a bound generic `Type` with a particular `Type` as a type parameter.  Once you have done that, you can use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create an instance of that type.  The generic type that you create could be based on an open generic class which is defined purely for this purpose, since it will be able to do anything with type `T` that it wants.  Note that if `T` has constraints upon it, the attempt to create the generic type will fail if the attempted type parameter does not satisfy those constraints.